# Returning multiple objects in callback

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a chart with the following array of objects.

```js
 var probeData = [ { min: 0.02, max: 1.44, avg: 0.73 },
                   { min: 0.06, max: 1.57, avg: 0.76 } ]
```

And the callback below.

```js
generateLabels: (_chart) => {
  return probeData.map((obj, i) => ({
    text: `UCL ${i+1} ${obj.max}`,
    index: i,
  })
);
```

Now, instead of returning only the `max`, I need to return, for each object also `min` and `avg`.

I tried the following solution but the callback returns only the two `avg` instead of the 6 values.

```js
generateLabels: (_chart) => {
  return probeData.map((obj, i) => ({
    text: `UCL ${i+1} ${obj.max}`,
    index: i,
  },
  {
    text: `LCL ${i+1} ${obj.min}`,
    index: i,
  },
  {
    text: `AVG ${i+1} ${obj.avg}`,
    index: i,
  }) 
);
```

[image]
What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share the error that you got?

Comment: What’s the chart library? [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration)?

Comment: did you intend to return an _array_? Or an outer object?

Comment: @Ry-  Ye chart.js. Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you show an example structure?

Comment: @CodeThing The legend should have 6 labels (min, max, avg for each object in probeData) and not just the two avg. Thanks

Comment: are you looking for flatmap

Comment: Anything left of your last comma in unused, you might need to look at using `flatmap` as @cmgchess suggests

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are probably looking for `flatMap`

```js
const probeData = [ { min: 0.02, max: 1.44, avg: 0.73 },
                   { min: 0.06, max: 1.57, avg: 0.76 } ]
                   
const res =  probeData.flatMap((obj, i) => [{
    text: `UCL ${i+1} ${obj.max}`,
    index: i,
  },
  {
    text: `LCL ${i+1} ${obj.min}`,
    index: i,
  },
  {
    text: `AVG ${i+1} ${obj.avg}`,
    index: i,
  }]) 
  
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accidentally using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator), but want to map one item to multiple objects. Try `Array.flatMap()`, as [cmgchess shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76179926/13561410).

---

The comma operator is a comma-separated list of expressions which evaluates to its last expression. In your case, the previous object initializations are therefore unused.

To return multiple objects in JavaScript, try returning them as part of another object (e.g. an array).

It seems you'd want to afterwards [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6626454/13561410) the resulting array of arrays. Instead of calling `Array.map()` followed by [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), JS provides [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for convenience.